# Не изменяются значения в Properties файле

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Делаю такое учебное задание:

У нас есть обычный класс *User* с такими полями и конструктором по умолчанию:

```
public class User {
   private int id=0; //id каждого новосозданного объекта = 0
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private long salary;

   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Нужно создать класс *ObjectMapper*, в котором будет метод - **public void save (Object obj)**, который бы делал следующее:

1. Принимал объект типа *User*;
2. Обращался к файлу (С:\props), где брал информацию о количестве уже сохраненных объектов (например, maxId = 5 (5 объектов уже были когда-то сохранены));
3. Икрементировал это значение (maxId++);
4. Присваивал это значение в  id поле объекта (т.е. у него id уже не 0, а 6);
5. Считывал все поля объекта и записывал их в файл (C:\Users);
6. Сохранил новое значение maxId в файле props (т.е. вместо maxId=5 стало maxId =6);

За файл props отвечает синглетный класс *LastIdSingleton*, который попросту его создает с изначальными значениями

```
public class LastIdSingleton {
private static LastIdSingleton instance;

private LastIdSingleton() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\props")); //Создает файл props
    pw.write("maxId = 0"); //c изначальной записью
    pw.close();
}

public static LastIdSingleton getInstance() throws FileNotFoundException {
    if(instance==null){
        instance = new LastIdSingleton();
    }  return instance;
}}
```

Код метода:

```
public class ObjectMapper {

public void save(Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException, IOException, NoSuchFieldException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {

    Class cl = obj.getClass();
    Field[] fields = cl.getDeclaredFields(); //Считываем поля которые есть у класса

    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true); //Даем доступ к private полям
    LastIdSingleton.getInstance(); //Создаем/вызываем синглетный класс
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\props"));

    int maxId = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("maxId")) ; //Получаем значение maxId из файла props

    if (fields[0].getInt(obj) == 0) {   // Сравниваем значение первого поля (id) сохраняемого объекта с 0лем (все новосозданные объекты по умолчанию имеют id = 0)
        String methName = "set" + fields[0].getName().toUpperCase().charAt(0) + fields[0].getName().substring(1); //Создаем имя сеттер-метода, который изменяет id (setId)
        maxId++; //Инкрементируем значение, которое отвечает за нумерацию объекта
        cl.getDeclaredMethod(methName, int.class).invoke(obj, maxId); //Вместо id = 0, объекту присваиваем новый id (id = maxId)

        props.setProperty("maxId", String.valueOf(maxId)); // Изменяем старое значение maxId (в файле props) на новое (maxId++)

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\props");
        props.store(fos,null); // Сохраняем изменения в файле props
        fos.close();

        //Считываем все поля объекта и  построчно записываем их в файл
        for (Field f : fields) {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\" + obj.getClass().getSimpleName(), true), "UTF-8")); // может дозаписывать

            String line = f.getType().getSimpleName() + " " + f.getName() + " " + f.get(obj) + "\r\n";
            pw.write(line);
            pw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

А теперь о проблеме.
Когда в main-e я 1й раз запускаю

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
om.save(new User());
```

Все проходит нормально, в файле props есть запись "maxId = 1",

в файле Users:

`int id 1
String name null
int age 0
long salary 0`

Но когда я дальше запускаю программу 2й раз(3й,4й,5й...), в файле props значение становится maxId = 0, а в файле Users вот такое:

`int id 1
String name null
int age 0
long salary 0
int id 1
String name null
int age 0
long salary 0
............`

***Кто-то может объяснить почему так происходит, и как сделать так, чтобы все Users записывались со своим уникальным id (по-порядку) и значение в props нормально изменялось при сохранении каждого нового объекта?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению не достаточно очков, чтобы ответить на свой вопрос.

Проблема была в том, что каждый раз, при запуске программы  создавался синглтон и задавал значение maxId=0;

Большое спасибо за внимание, **вопрос закрыт**.